# Can’t ssh to the router from the computer (windows) in the same comcast network

Tags: ssh, dd-wrt

I have a ASUS RT-N16 router flashed with DD-WRT. I connect it’s WAN port to a COMCAST modem. The problem is I can’t ssh to the router from the computer (windows) in the same comcast network. (just timeout)

First, if i connect the router with the computer directly, there is no problem (192.168.0.x ip). Second, I have a raspberry pi which is connected the same way as the router but there is no problem ssh to it from the computer.

I feel the issue is LAN or WAN support and some basic network knowledge I am missing.

The router ip is 10.0.0.6 my computer is 10.0.0.3. comcast gateway is 10.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Usually routers will not permit access from the WAN side of the network for security.

Why have you connected the router to your network? To provide WiFi access? Connecting it to via one of the LAN ports will integrate WiFi with your LAN; just make sure to disable the DHCP server on the router as having more than one DHCP server on your network is a sure way to get problems :-)